# "Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3/ React.js

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, zoom-sdk

I am building a zoom client app using react.js and trying to load stripe Payment Request Buttons in my app from below docs
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

I am able to see a Stripe Link button by loading the app in chrome browser, but when I am loading my app in zoom, I can't see that Link button, I am seeing "Unrecognized feature: 'payment'." in console.

I have not implemented any backend code for now, just trying to load stripe payment request buttons by passing publishable key first.

Any help will be really appreciated.

I want to load the stripe payment request buttons in my zoom client app.

Comment: It sounds like the Payment Request API isn't available in the browser/client: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Payment_Request_API, which is what the Payment Request Button relies on. Would recommend asking Zoom's support if it is. You may also need to reach out to Stripe Support for further assistance.

Comment: Clarifying question, you building a [Zoom App](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/zoom-apps/) and the Stripe payment request button is throwing the error? 

Since it's an embedded WebView, is the Stripe payment request button functioning correctly outside the Zoom App, in the browser itself?